# LINQ to XML finding elements that occur if later element is present

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Here is the XML I am dealing with:

[image]

And my code so far:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\morganjo\Desktop\bb-tasks.xml");

        var q = from val in doc.Descendants("property")
                select (string)val.Attribute("value");

        foreach (string str in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
```

That will get me the values of all the numbers in the element value. The problem I am having is this, **I only need the value if the element 'name' is equal to 'period' or 'delay'.** Since these occur after value, I am not sure how to get about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute order doesn't matter. You can take it's value and filter elements using it:

```
var q = from val in doc.Descendants("property")
        where (string)val.Attribute("name") == "delay" || (string)val.Attribute("name") == "period"
        select (string)val.Attribute("value");
```

Or using `let` keyword to get attribute value and then use it twice:

```
var q = from val in doc.Descendants("property")
        let name = (string)val.Attribute("name")
        where name == "delay" || value == "period"
        select (string)val.Attribute("value");
```

Comment: Wow thats awesome man, works great. Im still new to LINQ, this really helps. Will accept ASAP.